# is there a way to convert the data from <input type="file"/> to image in client side

Tags: html, reactjs

as i said i have:

```
            <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={(e) => onHandleProfileImageChange(e)} ></input>
```

and i get the files data and send it to the server, in the server i have multer so i get the image as a buffer and then i send the buffer back to the client in format base64, and i display it on the src of img tag.
now, is there a way to skip the sending data to the server and just get the buffer in the client, or maybe there is a better way than using buffer?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `image` state in `src` of `<img />`

```
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState("")
  const onHandleProfileImageChange = (e) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    const uploadedFile = e.target.files;
    if (uploadedFile[0] && uploadedFile[0].type.includes("image")) {
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(uploadedFile[0]);
      fileReader.onload = (event) => {
        setImage(event.target.result)
      };
    }
  };

  <input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" onChange={onHandleProfileImageChange} />
```

Comment: It's a hook exposed by react, so `React.useState("")`.